# PHP : Function - Return 2 variables (Boolean + $variable)

Tags: php, function, return

Issue Resolved : Here is the solution :

```
function testCoreq()
    {
        $coreqTest = makeCoreq();

        if(empty($coreqTest))
        {
            return array(true);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            foreach ($coreqTest as $ctest)
            {
                if($ctest['value'] == "true")
                {
                    return array(true);
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    return array(false,$ctest['coreqID']);
                }
            }
        }

    }

if(testCoreq()[0])
{
  //do something
}
else
{
  return testCoreq()[1]
}
```

I'm doing a school project and hit kind of a bump.

I created a function and i want it to either return "true" (boolean) or "false" (boolean) + a variable.

I searched the net quite a bit but wan't able to find a simple way to do this .

Is there any way to this this ?     //Thanks

The function is working properly but when it is returning the variable - it is also assuming that the function is returning "true" when i want it to return false + the value like :

```
else
                {
                    return $ctest['coreqID'];
                    return false;
                }
```

Here is the code :

```
function testCoreq()
    {
        $coreqTest = makeCoreq();

        if(empty($coreqTest))
        {
            return true;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            foreach ($coreqTest as $ctest)
            {
                if($ctest['value'] == "true")
                {
                    return true;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    return $ctest['coreqID'];
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

I am using it like this:

```
if (testCoreq())
{
 // do something
}
else
{
 // return the variable
}
```

but even if the first statement is false , then it is returning the variable - it is assuming the function is true.

Comment: u cant return 2 values in one return however u can enclose the values in an array and then return.

Comment: Return an `array(true, $value);` or pass 2 values [by reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

Comment: thanks - how do i check the first value & return the second one ?

Comment: You can not use `return` to return two variables. As other said, you can use array in the `return` to do it.

Comment: yep i already updated my code - but when i check the function - how i can use the first value of the array to test the boolean like : if (testCoreq[0])

Comment: Why do you use a `foreach` loop and in the first iteration you stop the function?

Comment: if even one of the value is true , then the function works & should return true instead of going on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to return -1 on true and other for false to decrease amount of returning values. Next option is to return array of values. The other option would be to pass reference variable in the function.

Comment: thx - how do i check the first value & if false - return the second array value : if (testCoreq())
{
 // do something
}
else
{
 // return the variable
}

Comment: You can save the results to the variable, and then check it, or do it immadiately with `if(testCoreq()[0])` if you are returning array like `array(true, $value);`

Comment: Thanks - got it working . Posting the working code above